# Can "semicircle" be used to refer to a part-circle that is not a exact half-circle?

Tags: grammaticality, mathematics

Going through a specification sheet for an engineering device, I glanced upon this phrase:

> ...the angular scanning range of the device is a semicircle of 300 degrees...

A semicircle is usually defined as a proper half of a circle - in mathematical terms a circle of angle 180 degrees. Clearly 300 degrees is more than a half, it is closer to being 5/6th of a circle. Is it grammatically correct to refer to non-full circles as a "semicircle", even though they are not exactly a half-circle.

Comment: I would say the word **arc** can be used: "an **arc** of 300 degrees," or perhaps: "the scanning range of the device is an **angle** of 300 degrees".

Comment: No, you can't use it. A semi-circle means half of a circle.

Comment: I presume it is clear from context that you are talking about geometric angle measure, not temperature. Thus, I would get rid of the "angular scanning range" as completely superfluous non-information. Instead, you may want to add actual information, like that it is scanning range in horizontal (or vertical) plane. Or is a sphere? Or half-sphere? Look at it from the point of view of a user of the device.

Comment: It *is* 5/6 of a circle.

Comment: @WeatherVane The word ***should*** needs to be used in "... the word arc can be used," not *can*. *Arc* it is, after all.

Comment: T Overload, how do you define a "semicircle?" Have you looked up a dictionary? And have you looked up an elementary geometry books?

Comment: @Kris I also made another suggestion which repositioned the word "angle", hence "can", not "should".

Comment: @WeatherVane Rephrasing is not an answer. The question framework limits the answer.

Comment: @Kris are you saying there are no synonyms of **arc** such as **angle** and **segment**? And are you saying that a question asking between two alternatives which are both incorrect should not have a better phrasing proposed?

Comment: @WeatherVane Atleast those three are not synonyms, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by Steven is correct, you cannot use semicircle in this case.
Here are some alternatives I would use:

> the angular scanning range of the device is an **arc** of 300 degrees...

Or if we want to give a sense of an area being scanned:

> the angular scanning range of the device is a **circular sector** of 300 degrees...

Here's the definition of [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)

Or simply:

> the angular scanning range of the device is 300 degrees...

I think this is the most technically accurate one. The angular range should be described as an angle, hence measured in degrees (or rads).

Answer (score 16):

In English, the prefix *semi-* usually means *partly*, as in *semiconscious* or *semiautomatic*.

But it can also mean half, as in *semiannually*, which always refers to something that happens every half-year (twice yearly).

The word semicircle has a specific defined meaning: *a half of a circle or of its circumference.* (Source: New Oxford American Dictionary)

So no, semicircle cannot be used to refer to any part of a circle that isn't 180 degrees.

Comment: This might be an unusual opinion, but when I hear "semiannually" I think "probably once every 2 years, but inconsistently so". I'm Australian, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Biannual is the term for something that happens every six months.  Not to be confused with biennial which is something that happens every two years.

Comment: @Clonkex "semi-" means half, and "bi-" (as in bicycle, which is how I remember the difference) means two.

Comment: Please read the FAQ. Good Luck.

Comment: @RonJohn I understand that, but that's not how I naturally interpret "semiannually". I only point this out because I may not be alone.

Comment: @Clonkex I understand that, but you're mistaken, and need to remember the correct meaning instead of digging in your heels.

Comment: @RonJohn Wtf? I'm not "digging in my heels". What on earth gave you that idea? All I did was mention how "semiannually" sounded to my ears, because it's potentially relevant. That's all. Literally nothing else was intended.